# Nhibernate in WPF - one session and errors

Tags: wpf, nhibernate, session

We has application what contains navigation bar with list customers and list tickets of customer.

[Image of MainWindow](http://s15.postimage.org/6yj1noqrf/mainwindow.png)

When customer in left list selected - in right list loading tickets.
NHibernate Session open on start for MainWindow. Loading tickets for every customer doing at BackgroundWorker in ViewModel.
In list now about 5000 customers. When I quick selected one customer and then next customer - if list of tickets first customer don't loaded yet - I get errors from nhibernate. Errors different: collection was processed twice by flush, found shared references to a collection and also list of tickets don't loaded in grid.
We don't want load tickets in main UI thread, because this freeze UI and tickets may be big count. How right work with NHibernate sessions in our application?

Answer (score 0):

i would do it as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee819139.aspx)

Open a stateless session in the backgroundthread to load the data for the maingrid and open a new session for each childwindow and load the selected item there with changetracking